# Site not showing in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I created a web application in Visual Studio 2013 and published it to my local machine.  It's not displayed in the sites list in IIS.  I tried to create the site in IIS and then point to the folder but I'm getting the following message:

The binding'*:80:' is assigned to another site.  If you assign the same binding to this site, you will only be able to start one of the sites.  Are you sure that you want to add this duplicate binding?

So I guess that means the site is actually there, I just don't know how to get it to show up in IIS?  Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add your site to IIS, Give the Host name a dummy name. See image.

Then open the `hosts` file, located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` with Notepad or some other text editor.

Add the following line and save

```
127.0.0.1   www.TrevorGoodchild.com
```

Now when you type `www.TrevorGoodchild.com` into the browser, it will go to your locally hosted website.
This works with all domain names, so should you use www.google.com, it will then also point to your local website when you type it in the browser.

[image]